# Christmas Countdown Off

Tags: java, long-integer, countdown

I am trying to make a Christmas countdown in java however I cannot seem to figure out why the hours are off. This is outputting about 12 hours off from the actual time.

Here is my code:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long christmas = 1387929600000L;
long untilChristmas = christmas - now;

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-kk-mm-ss");
Date date = new Date(untilChristmas);

System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

Comment: And just *why* are you hard-coding christmas?

Comment: At GMT your hard-coded Christmas time is right. System.currentTimeMillis() probably isn't operating on GMT (Based on your question you are +- 12 hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't hardcode the date, you should use a `Calendar` to calculate it:

```
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Calendar christmas = Calendar.getInstance();
    christmas.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
    christmas.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
    long untilChristmas = christmas.getTimeInMillis() - now;

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-kk-mm-ss");
    Date date = new Date(untilChristmas);

    System.out.println(df.format(date));
```